# How does python store things in lists vs integers?

Tags: python

If I do the following:

```
v = [0,0,0,0]
v2 = v
v[0]=5
print(v2)
```

the change to list v changes list v2.

```
a=5
b=a
a=6
print(b)
```

If I do this on the other hand, changing a doesnt change b. Whats the difference here? When I print id(a) and id(b) they give the same number, so shouldn't they be referencing the same object and change just like the list does?

Comment: `v` and `v2` are references to the same list and then you're using a reference to modify a list. Your second example is different because you assign `a` and `b` as references to the same thing first, and then reassign `a` to be a reference to something else - you're not mutating `5` to be `6` (`int` are immutable in Python, would probably be scary if they weren't). And an extra detail as to why `id` is the same for `a` and `b` when you set them to `5` is because CPython uses integer interning and keeps a static list of numbers in memory for the range `[-5, 256]`

Comment: The obligatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: "Whats the difference here?" The difference is that in one case you use a mutator method, `v[0]=5` which is essentially a call to `v.__setitem__(0,  5)`, this mutates the list in-place. On the other hand, `b=a` is simple assignment, and it doesn't mutate the `int` (int objects don't expose any mutator methods). Note, if you didi `v = [5, 0, 0, 0]` then `v2` wouldn't be affected either

Comment: "When I print id(a) and id(b) they give the same number, so shouldn't they be referencing the same object and change just like the list does?" No, **because you never change any `int` object anywhere in your code**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original question is really asking about two different things.

The first is this, with some annotation - you ask about lists. Lists are objects that are mutable sequences, and in your code, `v` and `v2` always refer to the same list. You can modify the contents of the list using any referrer to it and those changes are visible to anything that refers to it.

```
v = [0,0,0,0] # create a list object and assign reference to v

v2 = v        # assign v2 to be the reference to list v also refers to

v[0]=5        # modify first list element

print(v2)     # print the list v2 refers to, which is the same list v refers to
```

In the second piece of code you show, you're changing what a variable refers to, rather than changing the underlying value of an object.

```
a=5      # Assign a to be a reference to 5

b=a      # Assign b to be a reference to the thing a refers to

a=6      # Re-assign a to refer to 6, a now refers to a different object than b

print(b) # b still refers to 5
```

And you pointed out the use of `id`. I will also introduce [`sys.getrefcount()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount) which lets you see what the reference count for any particular object is, so we can see that, say, `v`'s referred-to list has multiple things referring to it.

```
import sys

v = [0,0,0,0] 

v2 = v        

v[0]=5        

print(f"id(v) = {id(v)}")
print(f"id(v2) = {id(v2)}")

# this shows 3 instead of 2 because getrefcount(x)
# increases refcount of x by 1
print(f"v referrers: {sys.getrefcount(v)}")

del v2 # remove v2 as a reference

# and this will show 2 because v2 doesn't
# exist/doesn't refer to it anymore
print(f"v referrers: {sys.getrefcount(v)}")

a = 5
b = 5
print(f"id(a) = {id(a)}")
print(f"id(b) = {id(b)}")

# you're reassigning a here, so the id will change
# but you didn't change what b refers to
a = 6
print(f"id(a) = {id(a)}")
print(f"id(b) = {id(b)}")
```

And the output of this would look something like this...

```
id(v) = 4366332480
id(v2) = 4366332480
v referrers: 3
v referrers: 2

id(a) = 4365582704
id(b) = 4365582704
id(a) = 4365582736
id(b) = 4365582704
```

And as I mentioned - CPython does some special stuff for numbers in the range of `[-5, 256]` and keeps a static list of them in memory, so `id` on any integer in that range should return the same value for any referrers to them.